# Why does != not work in this case and are there other options to say two things are not equal or should I just try and restart my code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a code for something as described below, but when I try and use it, a the shell returns a message (see below) saying I can't use the != because list indices must be integers or slices, not str, but when I do something like ['a'] != ['b'] or ['a', 'c'] != ['a', 'c'] in the shell, it works (first returns true and second returns false) and those are string lists so I'm not entirely sure what the problem is. Maybe the way I am writing the code makes it wrong or I don't need to use it all?

Why do I receive an error and are there alternatives to != or should I rewrite my code? (If my code seems completely off, it may be, I am a beginner and tried to construct it all on my own, I think/hope I'm headed in the right direction)

Code:

```
 def remove_match(list1, list2):
'''(list, list) -> list
Given two lists of a single character strings, return a new list
that contains only the characters in list1 that were not the same string
and in the same position in list 2. Both list1 and list2 
have the same length.
>>>remove_match(['P', 'O', 'Y', 'R'], ['P', 'B', 'G', 'R'])
['O', 'Y']
>>>remove_match(['P', 'G', 'G', 'R'], ['P', 'G', 'G', 'R'])
[]
>>>remove_match(['O', 'R', 'B', 'Y'], ['P', 'P', 'P', 'P'])
['O', 'R', 'B', 'Y']
'''
edit_list1=[]
for i in list1:
    if list1[i] != list2[i]:
        edit_list1.append(list1[i])
return edit_list1
```

The message that comes up when I try and use the function (such as one of the doc string examples ) is:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  Python Shell, prompt 2, line 1
  File "/Users/Rir/Desktop/folder/file.py", line 56, in <module>
    if list1[i] != list2[i]:
 builtins.TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Thanks!

Comment: `i in list1` corresponds to a value, not an index.

Comment: You could try enumerate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`i in list1` corresponds to a value, not an index.

What you really want to do is probably:

```
edit_list1=[]
for i in list1:
    if i != list2[list1.index(i)]:
        edit_list1.append(i)
return edit_list1
```

Comment: `i != list2[list1.index(i)]` not OK if multiple instances of `i` in `list1`, `list1.index(i)` will always be the index of the 1st occurance of `i`

Comment: Hi Nae, can you describe what is happening in the third line (if i != list2[...) of your code? Does it mean if a character in list1 (ie. i) does not equal the list2 character at the same index (the square brackets), then put them in edit list1 (4th line)?

Comment: Yes it does. But I'd rather checkout the other answers, which are by far more pythonic and more accurate and generally applicable.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, list indices must be integer. You can use enumerate() to get the index and the content at the same time. Then run it through loop.

However, I suggest you to use list comprehension.

```
list1 = ['P', 'O', 'Q', 'Y']
list2 = ['P', 'O', 'Q', 'A']

list_nomatch = [x for x in list1 if x not in list2]
```

This will produce 'Y'. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

you probably wanted an incrementing integer index `i`

```
def remove_match(list1, list2):
    edit_list1=[]
    for i in range(len(list1)):  # get indices from range the length of your list
        if list1[i] != list2[i]:
            edit_list1.append(list1[i])
    return edit_list1
```

`zip()` is good for "parallel" operations on lists:

```
def remove_match(list1, list2):
    edit_list1=[]
    for a, b in zip(list1, list2):  # zip lists together, get elements in pairs
        if a != b:                  # test on the paired elements, no indexing
            edit_list1.append(a)
    return edit_list1
```

and as shown in other answers you loop matches the List Comprehension pattern

```
def remove_match(list1, list2):
    return [a for a, b in zip(list1, list2) if a != b]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since both lists are of the same size, you can use `enumerate()` -

```
def remove_match(list1, list2):
  edit_list1=[]
  for idx, i in enumerate(list1):
    if i != list2[idx]:
      edit_list1.append(i)
  return edit_list1

print(remove_match(['P', 'O', 'Y', 'R'], ['P', 'B', 'G', 'R']))
print(remove_match(['P', 'G', 'G', 'R'], ['P', 'G', 'G', 'R']))
print(remove_match(['O', 'R', 'B', 'Y'], ['P', 'P', 'P', 'P']))
```

Output -

```
['O', 'Y']
[]
['O', 'R', 'B', 'Y']
```

The same code using List Comprehension -

```
def remove_match(list1, list2):
  return [i for idx, i in enumerate(list1) if i != list2[idx]]
```